be at ease and rest assured when the subject is not "you"
Browsing some dictionaries, I found that most examples using "rest assured" begin with "you" as the subject and it seems to guarantee that what follows it is true, for example,

You can rest assured [=you can be sure] that we won't be late.

which makes me wonder if these sentences are correct:


Since several oil wells have been discovered, people can rest assured that oil price is going to decline.




(A mother reassuring a child who is afraid that her dad will forget her presents)



Your dad is going to buy you a lot of toys, so just rest assured, alright?


Also, can I replace "rest assured" with "be at ease" without changing the meanings of the sentences?

It seems to me that people use rest assured to put the listener on edge, not to put the listener at ease.  You can rest assured, the politicians will see that they themselves have great health insurance with low deductibles and that pays for any drug under the sun.

@TimR - that's a sarcastic usage, surely? Customers can rest assured that supplies of tomatoes will continue during our rebuilding work at this store. No putting on edge there.

@MichaelHarvey I don't think I've ever heard it used non-sarcastically.  It's like "mark my word" or "you wait and see".  It's used to deliver an unpleasant prediction. Maybe in BrE it's different.

@TimR - yes, maybe it's an AmE/BrE difference: Assured - formal used to emphasize that what you say is true or will definitely happen. You may rest assured that we will do all we can to find him (Oxford Learners' Dictionary), also Our durable charcoal grey composite decking is covered by a 10 year warranty, so you can rest assured that those boards are built to last! UK company) If something should go wrong, you can rest assured that you will receive the full support of our UK customer care network.

@TimR - typically, in UK usage, rest assured is used to [re]assure.

@MichaelHarvey  I would distinguish in AmE between "You may rest assured, we..." where it is a formal reassurance,  and "You can rest assured, {someone else, it}" where it is like "mark my words".

@TimR - I don't think President Biden was being sarcastic when he said this on March 13, 2023: First, all customers who had deposits in these banks can rest assured — I want to — rest assured they’ll be protected and they’ll have access to their money as of today.  That includes small businesses across the country that banked there and need to make payroll, pay their bills, and stay open for business. and also this (same speech) Look, the bottom line is this: Americans can rest assured that our banking system is safe.  Your deposits are safe.

I mean in daily conversation.  I don't think people say it to each other in casual conversation in its reassuring sense.   A doctor might say it to a patient to reassure them.  The reassurance requires at least a semi-formal context, in my experience. Otherwise it's "mark my words".

Of course there will always be sarcastic usages of just about any positive thing, and sarcastic use of a normally reassuring utterance is a pretty common way of warning or alerting people.

I might easily say to my wife 'rest assured that I won't forget to water the plants while you're away',

Ah, that's not something I would expect to hear in a domestic setting.  The AmE domestic version is "Don't worry, ..."

Also, it's usually rest assured that..., and you wouldn't say it to a child. The mother in (2) would certainly say "Don't worry" or "You needn't worry".

Your rest assured sentence isn’t wrong, but neither does it feel idiomatic, especially if the people referred to don’t include the listener.
Be at ease is not a collocation that is often used. Instead, one typically uses conjugated forms of be, as in Now that she’s gotten to know her colleagues better, she is more at ease at the office.

Yes, you can say "rest assured" with the person receiving the assurance being someone other than "you". "I can rest assured ..." "Sally can rest assured ..." etc.
Is "be at ease" a synonym of "rest assured"? Hmm, they're at least very close in meaning. "You can be at ease that George will complete the job", "You can rest assured that George will complete the job". Like any synonyms, if you worked at it hard enough you could probably come up with some examples where one works and the other doesn't or they don't mean quite the same thing. But yeah, at least mostly the same.

So, @Jay, here we have not a transatlantic difference in usage, but perhaps a trans-Appalachian one. To your Michigander ear they sound okay, and to my Marylander ear they don’t.

@PaulTanenbaum Fair enough. A constant danger in talking about "English" is that there are many dialects of English, and what people say in Michigan may be completely different from what people say in Maryland. I try to at least mention such differences when I'm aware of them, but I'm not always.

Like I'm not a Michigander any more. I now live in the Philippines. They speak English here, but there are many subtle differences from my Michigan English. Like my Filipina wife once commented that she had trouble understanding something I said because of my "slang". I wasn't using any slang, I was using plain English words. But in the Philippines, "slang" means "accent". (I have some funnier examples but they take longer to explain.)

Yeah, @Jay, me too (re restricting my descriptions to my own dialect). Oh, and a Brit would likely have said “different to what people say in Maryland.” :-) But then again, they’d also likely say “Mary Land,” they, who shrink the pronunciation of Cholmondeley down to “Chumley.” Go figure.

@PaulTanenbaum a Brit would likely have said “different to what people say in Maryland.” Some Brits might, and others (like this one) would --at least mentally-- correct it to 'different from', and if they had editing responsibility, change it.
